# InvalidPluginRequestException Gradle AndroidStudio

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, android-studio-3.0

I have imported existing android project after 2 months, and when it started to sync the gradle, it gave some strange error, because earlier the project was working properly.
The error is `Caused by: org.gradle.plugin.management.internal.InvalidPluginRequestException: Plugin 'com.android.application' is already on the script classpath.`

below is my gradle file :
**build.gradle (:app)**

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'com.google.gms.google-services'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 30
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.quickshop"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}



dependencies {
    implementation 'com.hbb20:ccp:2.5.0'
    implementation 'com.steelkiwi:badge-holder-view:1.1.0'

    implementation 'com.mikhaellopez:circularimageview:4.2.0'
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:3.1.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
    implementation 'pl.droidsonroids.gif:android-gif-drawable:1.2.22'
    implementation 'me.himanshusoni.quantityview:quantity-view:1.2.0'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.9.0'
    implementation 'pl.droidsonroids.gif:android-gif-drawable:1.2.22'
    implementation 'com.github.MindorksOpenSource:EditDrawableText:2.0'

    implementation 'com.razorpay:checkout:1.6.6'
    implementation 'in.shadowfax:proswipebutton:1.2.2'

    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:20.0.4'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.2.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.2.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-config:19.0.3'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging'
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:26.8.0')
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:3.2.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:19.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:19.6.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:19.2.1'

    implementation 'cc.cloudist.acplibrary:library:1.2.1'

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
    implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:2.3.2'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:2.3.2'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:2.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.2.0'
    implementation 'com.github.barteksc:android-pdf-viewer:2.8.2'

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'
}
```

**build.gradle(project)**

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.5'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

**settings.gradle**

```
include ':app'
rootProject.name = "QuickShop"
```

I tried to find solution for this, but didnt find a proper solution that can resolve this issue, can anyone please help me with this and this new gradle plugin invocation.

android version : Android Studio Arctic Fox | 2020.3.1 Patch 3,
gradle version : 4.1,
Android gradle plugin version : 3.0.1

Comment: Change buildToolsVersion "30.0.2"
To buildToolsVersion "30.0.3"
Then it will work like magic.

Comment: No luck, still error is there..